# How to change xib with localized language in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

How can I change my app language as I am using `xibs` in my project.

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Clients"; ObjectID = "22E-Bc-4Af"; */
"22E-Bc-4Af.text" = "Klienci";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Messages"; ObjectID = "5y0-E0-aXx"; */
"5y0-E0-aXx.text" = "Wiadomości";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Calendar"; ObjectID = "H9g-zr-B2l"; */
"H9g-zr-B2l.text" = "Kalendarz";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Settings"; ObjectID = "Hxq-Ij-R8l"; */
"Hxq-Ij-R8l.text" = "Ustawienia";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Recommend"; ObjectID = "ka7-JK-tWz"; */
"ka7-JK-tWz.text" = "Poleć";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Label"; ObjectID = "pYM-Zf-LI7"; */
"pYM-Zf-LI7.text" = "Label";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Shop"; ObjectID = "zhW-HV-pnE"; */
"zhW-HV-pnE.text" = " Zakupy";
```

The `xib` is not changing when I change the app language, only the changes from the `.string` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't internationalize one `xib` directly. There are possibilities if you add a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) for each component.

Sample:

```
@implementation UILabel (i18n)

- (void)localizeFromNib {
    if (self.text.length > 0) {
        self.text = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:self.text value:@"" table:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

But manually implement this is very hard work and may contain errors.
I recommend you use `AGi18n` `Pod`, it already makes internationalization of each component.

- https://cocoapods.org/pods/AGi18n
- https://github.com/angelolloqui/AGi18n